# Social Signin Invalid CSRF Token

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, jhipster, spring-social

I have an issue with jhipster application sign in functionality. When I try to login with Google or Facebook from the Login form I get :

> Sorry, an error has occurred.
>   Status: Forbidden (Forbidden)
>   Message: Invalid CSRF Token '0f400828-c705-4cb2-9de0-b24c005152bf' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.

The strange thing is that it works from Register form.
I am using jHipster version v4.3.0 and angularjs.

Comment: Are you using nodeBB?

Comment: Nope. I use Jhipster yeoman generator.

Comment: Is it the latest version?

Comment: No. It says it is 4.3.0, but probably it is around 3.6 - 3.9 because I install new version for different project.